# Set Date to next day of week

Tags: java, android, date

I am using firebase and building a application with Android.

I have a `DatePicker`, where I can pick the day of week, hour and minutes.

When I pick the date and press submit, I want to store not the current date, or not even the date selected, but the next date related to the dayOfWeek chosen.

Imagine I choose Thursday, tomorrow is Thursday I want to save that date and the hour chosen by the current user either.

At the moment I tried something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfWeek);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
dateMatch = calendar.getTime();
```

The hour and minutes are fine, but how can I store the next day/month/year?

Comment: use `add` method on `Calendar` object

Comment: you can add the 7 days in the selected date in  calendar, you will  get the dayofweek choose in next week

Comment: i used add on the calendar, but i want the next day of week, it can be less then 7 days, for example today is monday, tommorrow is tuesday, if i choose tuesday i want to get the tommorrow date, at the moment when i choose tuesday i get day 11 :S

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of(
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
             .with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.THURSDAY ) ) ,
    LocalTime.of( hours , minutes ) ,
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
).toString()
```

The [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class adjusts the time-of-day if invalid for that date in that zone.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes. Avoid the troublesome old legacy date-time classes seen in the Question.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Determine the `DayOfWeek` enum object represented by your UI widget. If tracking by number, that class numbers 1-7 for Monday-Sunday per ISO 8601 standard.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.of( 1 ) ;  // Monday=1.
```

Use a `TemporalAdjuster` found in `TemporalAdjusters` to determine the next date with that same day-of-week.

```
LocalDate ld = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( dow ) ) ;
```

Instantiate a `LocalTime` from your hours and minutes numbers.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( hours , minutes );
```

Combine to determine an actual moment in the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Your particular time-of-day may not be valid for that date in that zone because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). The `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts as needed. Be sure to read the class doc to understand its policies in making that adjustment.

You can serialize that object to text using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, extended by this class to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

```
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

Reconstitute the object by parsing such strings.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: thank you friend, do you know a way to do that with calendar?

Comment: @AntonioCosta **Avoid using `java.util.Calendar`**. That class is poorly designed, flawed, and confusing – a bloody mess.The java.time classes were developed to replace `Calendar`, `Date`, and such. See the last part of the section I added to my Answer, for using a back-port of java.time in Android. Well worth the bother of adding to your project.